# Symfony 2.0.9 and wrong PropelBundle version

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, vendors

I'm having troubles with PropelBundle versions using Symfony 2.0.9.

> ErrorException: User Deprecated: The PropelBundle uses a new branching model, you should switch to the 1.0 branch (1.0.x versions). For more information, please read: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/wiki in /home/project_path/vendor/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle/PropelBundle.php line 28

However, in the deps file PropelBundle version is set to 1.0 like it's reccomended here: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/wiki

> [PropelBundle]
>       git=git://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle.git
>       target=/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle
>       version=origin/1.0
>
> [phing]
>       git=git://github.com/Xosofox/phing.git
>       target=/phing
>
> [propel]
>       git=git://github.com/propelorm/Propel.git
>       target=/propel
>       version=origin/1.0
>
> [doctrine-fixtures]
>       git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git
>
> [DoctrineFixturesBundle]
>       git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
>       target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
>       version=origin/2.0

I tried to reinstall vendors, but nothing changed.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Williams I fixed this problem, however now i have this error:

> ./composer.phar update nothing
>   Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.phing.info
>   Updating dependencies
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-mongo * is missing from your system.
>     Problem 2
>       - doctrine/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongo * -> no matching package found.
>       - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master.
>       - doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb dev-master.
>       - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle dev-master.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.

These packages are required for AdminGenerator, which I'm trying to install.

Comment: Can you check commit hash inside PropelBundle? Should be `a712d9e4aa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems you use a old version of your vendors.

First, remove your Phing configuration, and use the official repository: https://github.com/phingofficial/phing

Then, remove your PropelBundle vendor (rm -rf vendor/.../PropelBundle) and reinstall it. This message only appears if you track the master branch.

Comment: It fixed this problem, but now i get: "The requested PHP extension ext-mongo * is missing from your system" and "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master" after running 'composer.phar install'.

Comment: Then it's an other problem :)